# How to transfer a file over pen and paper, with error correction

Tags: file-transfer, paper, data-integrity, handwriting

I'm looking for a way to transfer a file using only a pen and paper.

This is somewhat similar to [paperbak](http://ollydbg.de/Paperbak/), except the density I'm looking for is much, much lower, and I don't want to use a printer or a scanner.

Obviously, the first answer is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. But writing and reading such a high number of characters is bound to result in errors. For my purposes, any error is unacceptable.

The second answer might be [Reed-Solomon error correcting codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) (for example, using [rsbep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/rsbep.1.html)). However, this is also a problem, because from my understanding, Reed-Solomon codes don't correct insertion/deletion errors, which are probably more likely than substitution errors in this case.

Is there any program which will encode/decode arbitrary files with insertion/deletion aware error correcting codes? Preferably it should work on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X

Obviously any other solution to the general problem is welcome.

Comment: Do you expect errors in writing, or just reading?

Comment: I expect errors in both, but I'd also expect them to be equivalent...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread and thought you were printing. You want to write it out by hand?

Comment: yes, by hand (filling character limit with this parathentical remark)

Comment: How much data are you hoping to encode this way? To minimize copying errors, you'd have to encode the data using easily identified/distinguished alphanumeric characters. That means at minimum you'd need to use 2 characters to represent each byte. Assuming, you can fit 400 words per page at an average word length of 5 characters, you'd only get about 1kb of data on a sheet of A4 paper. The average person copies at 22 words (110 characters) per minute. So it'd take about 18 minutes to copy 1kb of data, or about 13 days (no sleep) to copy 1MB of data. And this is without error correction.

Comment: How many colors of pens can I use? :)

Comment: Only a single color pen, otherwise transcribing it will be too difficult.  I'm actually transmitting compressed, signed, encrypted text, so assuming even a 50% redundancy rate, the total amount of writing will be <1.5 times as much as actually writing out the original text would be (once you take into account the compression).  However, there is the issue that copying random characters is harder than copying English text.  So to answer your question, certainly only in the couple of kb range.

Comment: Hmmm, in fact, I've done a little test with an essay of mine.  Original essay: 14,116 bytes =>nanozip compressed: 4,118 bytes => base64 encoded: 5565 bytes.  with almost 50% redundancy, we still have cut the number of characters to copy in *half*.  In fact, if you don't like copying characters, but want to copy text instead, stenographically encoding it using http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/stego.html still only increases the size by about a factor of four, so we are left with an essay only twice as big as our original.  Pretty good, huh?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if `otherwise transcribing it will be too difficult` is going to be a problem.

Let's say you have Red, Green, Blue and Black. You can write a script that turns your data into a collection of letters from `RGBY`, eg: `RGBYGBRYBGBYRYYBYBRYYG` (or even `Red Green Blue Black Green Blue Red Black...` in an Excel sheet) and back again. It's just a matter of base converting your binary data from base 2 (or hexadecimal data from base 16) to the base in the amount of colors you take (4 in this example).

Now, the most logical approach would be to get yourself 16 colors. This way, you have to use **4 times less dots** which makes switching between the pens worth it. This allows you to write 4 times as much data on the paper if you need to, or perhaps have can be 4 times less accurate when putting your dots, the scaling is up to you. I would really advise against drawing every single bit.

For instance, `5565 bytes` would have to be multiplied by two to get the amount of hexadecimals which is `11130 hexadecimals` (as opposed to `44520 bits`) which can be put into a `106 x 106` grid.

Depending on the type of data you probably can come with some optimizations...

**Hint:** Attempt to pick the most distinct (most contrasting) colors...

**Alternatives that can use a single pen:**

- Represent the different hexadecimals by different symbols `-`, `/`, `|`, `\`, `+`, ...
- Represent the different hexadecimals by a small pixel font, see my avatar.

  [image]

  This makes it even useful to use something like Base 32 (or Base 36). Note that the `Q` and `9` are the same, so you will want the top right pixel of the `Q` to be White for a clear distinction. Base 32 only requires a `53 x 53` grid for your example, plus a small  bit of spacing to distinct between letters.

Comment: Well, there's a few issues with this.  1. I'm colorblind.  2. It requires buying a bunch of pens. 3. It doesn't help at all with the error correction. 4. It involves writings codes instead of text, which humans are worse at.

Comment: @JeremySalwen: Uhm, writing characters in a grid is not really hard. And you can correct errors by writing some extra longitudinal check numbers or a CRC. But really, it's very easy to write over letters from a grid to a grid, worst case you just go over it again to validate.

Comment: @JeremySalwen: And if you're color blind, you just don't take any of the colors for which you are color blind.

Comment: Color blindness is more of a dimensionality reduction of color space than it is a selective inability to see certain colors.  I mean, I probably could pull off Black, Blue, Yellow, Red, Green, Gray, but not much more

Comment: @Tom You should probably put your old avatar in to prevent confusion :)

Comment: Done, @NateKoppenhaver. :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want people to be able to read and write the data, the problem with Base64 and many text encodings is that they use characters like I, l, 1, |, /, 0, O, o, and so on that people confuse with each other.

Investigate Douglas Crockford's [Base32](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html) encoding. Its alphabet was specifically chosen to avoid similar characters, and it includes error detection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use this, but it still doesn't solve the error correction problem.

Comment: @Jeremy, Crockford's implementation includes error *detection*. If you need to correct errors, investigate Forward-Error Correction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction).

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, that sounds more reasonable. I just wasn't sure if you were intending on encoding megabytes of data like this.

I'd recommend, along the lines of Oliver's suggestion, that you increase your data density by borrowing a page from [Bacon's cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher), which prison gangs often use to encode hidden messages in missives written in 2 different script styles--usually either upper vs. lowercase characters or print vs. cursive characters, e.g.

```
Hey mOM, WHAT's FOR diNNeR TODAY? = ABBBA AAAAA BAAAB BAABA AAAAA
                                  =   P     A     S     T     A
```

However, since your goal isn't stegnography, you would simply use this to expand your glyph set. Doing this, you could have up to 114 glyphs just using print & cursive alphanumeric characters, or 12996 code points using dual-character encoding.

However, since all glyph counts greater than 15 and less than 256 are essentially the same for a straight cipher of binary data (meaning, you'll still need 2 characters to represent each byte, giving you a data density of 4 bits per character in all cases), you can use the extra 98 glyphs / 12740 code points for error detection/correction.

Ways to do this include:

- Choose a set of the 256 most easy to read/write character combos. If any other character combo occurs, you know it's a copying error.
- Use two versions of the end character as a parity bit.
- Create 50 different 16-character glyph sets. You can then use them to cipher encode error correction data.

  E.g. `{set 1}{set 1}` means the next 3 nibbles equal `0x000`, `{set 1}{set 2}` equals `0x001`, etc.

  You can use this to represent 2500+ of the 4096 possible 1.5 byte values. Similarly, you could use just 16 sets to represent all values of the following byte, giving you 100% redundancy without increasing your encoded data length.

Alternatively, you could use the extra glyphs for additional compression:

- Implement variable-width encoding by choosing 98 single-character code points. This would reduce the average encoded content size by about 20%.
- Implement something similar to run-length encoding by using different glyph sets or glyph set combinations to represent repeating nibbles/bytes. E.g. `Ab` = `aba`; `aB` = `abab`; `AB` = `ababab`...
- Use the extra glyphs or code points to represent "words" and "phrases" that are repeated in your data. Though pre-compressed data will likely have a high level of entropy, so I don't know how effective this would be.

---

To further reduce copying errors, I would display the encoded content in gridlines and copy onto graphing paper. If you can use custom stationary that has alternating column/row colors or a chessboard-style checkered grid with lettered columns & numbered rows for quick look-ups, that would further increase copying accuracy.

You can also combine an alternating grid layout with alternating character styles as an easy form of error detection. I.e. if odd columns are always capitalized, if the transcriber finds themselves writing lowercase letters in odd columns, then they know they've made an error and can start tracking back to see where it happened.

---

Though if your main priority is accuracy, I would use a binary encoding + [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code). Using a (12, 8) shortened Hamming code on standard graphing paper, you might only fit 187 bytes, encoding only 124 bytes of data. But it could be transcribed very quickly (a slash for 1, nothing for 0) and provide single error correction. Tacking on an extra parity bit (13, 8) would provide SECDED (single error correction, double error detection). Using a standard hamming code like (15, 11) or (31, 26), you get even better efficiency with 137 and 156 bytes of data per sheet, respectively. Even higher code rates can be achieved, depending on how accurate you think your transcriber can be.

A binary encoding would also be easier to read (aloud) and OCR/OMR.

Comment: Obviously I am planning on using upper case characters as well. Out of all the error correction schemes you have suggested, I don't see any way to implement them without designing a custom file format, etc.  Is there really no precedent for putting error correcting protection on files?  Perhaps I should also have mentioned that creating custom programs is also highly undesired?  I can't seem to find any program which will just protect your files with error correcting codes.

Comment: My point wasn't to just use upper case characters but to also use different scripts/fonts. If you only use upper & lowercase alphanumeric characters, you only have 62 glyphs, or 3844 code points. You can get more than triple that amount of code points by using 2 scripts, taking advantage of the storage medium being used for the transfer, which was the purpose of my answer. If you don't want to take advantage of the fact that this is a written medium, then there are plenty of file formats that implement error encoding. Most archive/compression formats have error correction built in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by creating new file formats though. All of the techniques I mentioned are meant for visually encoding arbitrary binary data in handwritten text/marks. You wouldn't store them on the computer like that (you couldn't beyond storing a scanned image). Basically, you would have a program to encode the data, outputting an image on the screen for the user to copy down. Then to transfer it back onto a computer, you would use a decoding program that either OCR/OMR's the scanned image or accepts the input via keyboard (e.g. `alt`+`a` for cursive "a").

Comment: See, that's what I have the problem with: "you would have a program to encode the data"...no, I don't.  I don't have a program to do this, and I don't know of any program to do this.  I am also not aware of any file format that can gracefully handle a byte *removed* (not erased) from near the beginning of the file on top of other errors.  I definitely agree that these are methods for increasing data density, but that's not my primary concern now, it's ease of reading/writing and error protection.

Comment: @Jeremy: As I said, most archive formats have error-correction built in which seems to work well enough for most people. But if you want something specially designed for hand-transcribing, then you're gonna need to write or have someone write something for you. Otherwise, your best bet is to look into existing applications designed for transmitting over high noise channels. Though the easiest option with no concern for data density is to just use an RAR file with high level of error correction, and then repeat the header section 3 times for triple modular redundancy.

Comment: The only tools you'd need to do this is an RAR program like WinRAR and a hex editor like Frhed.

Comment: No.  I made a 28K rar file.  Added recovery volumes to it with >50% recovery volumes.  Base64 encoded it.  Deleted six characters from the contents and added two.  Base64 decoded it.  rar COULD NOT recover the file.  That is completely unacceptable for any sort of use that I've described.  I'm not sure what "well enough for most people" is, but if it cannot correct a 0.02% error rate with >50% redundancy, then it certainly is not well enough for me.  I don't care if it's something specifically designed for hand transcribing, but yes, my question is what can I use that *will* work.

Answer (score 1):

We used to use [S-Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_%28file_format%29) for this purpose. There was a simple checksum, per line, for error detection. Normally all but the last line was fixed length, so the end-of-line marker served as a check for insertions and deletions. There was no check for missing lines though. For this we simply counted the number of lines. Mostly files were short, less than 100 lines, but I do remember at least one which had 300 lines or more. It was *very* tedious typing files into the system. Of course, among the first programs transferred this way was a downloader ;)

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin ecosystem has created two such format:

- [bech32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) is a format meant to be produced and understandable by both humans and machines. It contains error correction.
- a [BIP39](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase) mnemonic phrase contains a checksum, and the natural redundancy of natural languqge words can be seen as error-correction.

while they both come from the bitcoin world but can be applied to any data.

Comment: Very cool, only limitation is it maxes out at 90 characters.

Comment: added BIP39, with no size limit

Answer (score 0):

[Optical Mark Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition) has been used for decades to create machine-readable handwritten forms. The Wikipedia page has links to several Open Source versions.

Schools have long used OMR for testing; the forms are simple to use and to read, and accuracy is typically better than keyboard input. For higher accuracy, commercial manufacturers like Scantron and ReMark can create custom forms.

Comment: That's interesting, unfortunately, this requires a scanner or some other imaging system attached to the computer to work.